# Configuring IHS server to direct traffic to the Netty component bound to a port

Tags: websphere, netty, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce, ibmhttpserver

I have a Server Component ( based on Jboss-Netty, which could maintain & handle persistent connections ) deployed in WAS. This component when deployed & initiated within the WAS environment, binds to a port & listens for incoming HTTP connection.

[ Why i had to deploy a Netty HTTP Server within WAS is another story - management requirement !! Netty is deployed in WAS as a spring bean which when initiated runs on a port in the machine, independent of WAS ]

Clients (mobile app) were able to establish persistent HTTP connections (to the above URL::Port) with this netty component & send/receive requests.

**Now, I have to replicate this feature in our Production Environment where a IHS Server (Web Server) which sits before the WAS.**

What i expected is to get a IHS URL which could redirect the incoming packets to the specific PORT on WAS, so that the Client apps can establish a similar persistent http connection.

Our Server Admin tried a few combinations and we are not able to identify how to proceed further on this.

Your expert ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working? As far as I can tell, you're saying that the Netty server takes over some port that is not the one used by WAS, correct? So as long as that port isn't one being listened to by IHS, I wouldn't think anything is different.

Comment: My http requests have to go through IHS which would then redirect it to the Port where netty is running. Admin team over here are yet to find a way to do this :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what "combinations" your administrator attempted, but from what you describe, what you need to do is set up a reverse proxy. IHS is basically Apache HTTP server, so you can use the following for reference:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Apologies, i wasn't made aware of what Admin is trying. I would ask them try the above. Thanks